# Want to get seperate tokens from a line scanned in from a file. Java

Tags: java, date, java.util.scanner

I'm doing a date program that reads in dates and displays date ranges and invalid dates. To start I am reading in a line at a time and formatting the line the way I wish. However, I also want to take the month, day, and year from the String line I read in into separate variables I can work with. The data I read in looks like:

```
    June 17, 1997
    July 23, 1997
    September 28, 1980
    September 31, 1980
    Mar. 2, 1980
    Apr. 2, 1980
    May 3, 1980
    Nov 25, 1989
    Dec 25, 1989
    Jan 3, 1973
```

A snippet of my code so far looks like

```
  Scanner in = null;
    try {
        in = new Scanner(new File("dates.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException exception) {
        System.err.println("failed to open dates.txt");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    while (in.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = in.nextLine();
        line = line.replace(".", "");
        line = line.replace(",", "");
    }
```

So my question is, how can I "scan" my line variable and separate it into different token/variables of month, day, year. Or could I possibly scan for string tokens initially, instead of scanning the whole line, and reform them to what I want (getting rid of commas and periods), then parse them into ints? And if that's possible, what's the operation to parse it into a int?

Comment: You can try StringTokenizer

Comment: Using regex would work as well. `line` now contains month space day space year. A very lazy pattern which would capture the three groups could be something like: `(.*?)\s(.*?)\s(.*?)`. To convert a string to an int, use `Integer.parseInt(string)` (see here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String))

Comment: The int part is just int number = Integer.parseInt(myString); assuming the string is valid as an int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this..

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class ParseFileName {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner in = null;
    try {
      in = new Scanner(new File("dates.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException exception) {
      System.err.println("failed to open dates.txt");
      System.exit(1);
    }
    while (in.hasNextLine()) {
      String line = in.nextLine();
      line = line.replace(".", "");
      line = line.replace(",", "");

      StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line);
      String strMonth = st.nextToken();
      String strDay = st.nextToken();
      String strYear = st.nextToken();

      Integer day = Integer.parseInt(strDay);
      Integer year = Integer.parseInt(strYear);
      //...
    }
  }
```

}

Now, you need to make sure your lines are always like that, otherwise the nextToken will need a validation.. like using hasMoreTokens method. You can also write a mapping method if you need to get integers for months.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for! Well, the approach I want to go with.

Comment: @DLR great, remember to close the question.

Answer (score 1):

There are more than one ways to skin a cat:

You could use a regexp

```
String[] strings = new String[3];

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w+) (\\d+), (\\d+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(inputString);
if(m.matches()) {
   for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
      strings[i] = m.group(i+1);
   }
}
```

The most handy tool for this is the [Java online regex checker here](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html)

You could have a different approach: instead of reading the whole lines, and then separating them into fields, you could try reading the fields one by one using [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)'s appropriate methods:

> [public String **next()**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29)
>
> Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. A complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the delimiter pattern. This method may block while waiting for input to scan, even if a previous invocation of hasNext() returned true.
>
> [public int **nextInt(int radix)**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29)
>
> Scans the next token of the input as an int. This method will throw InputMismatchException if the next token cannot be translated into a valid int value as described below. If the translation is successful, the scanner advances past the input that matched.
>   If the next token matches the Integer regular expression defined above then the token is converted into an int value as if by removing all locale specific prefixes, group separators, and locale specific suffixes, then mapping non-ASCII digits into ASCII digits via Character.digit, prepending a negative sign (-) if the locale specific negative prefixes and suffixes were present, and passing the resulting string to Integer.parseInt with the specified radix.

Or, you could use the [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to handle the different formats you have

```
SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMM d, yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat format2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM. d, yyyy");
```

Comment: I wanted to use this sort of method at first, but not too familiar with syntax with java at the moment. But thank you for the input. I did think of using something like this because I was used to Perl's reg exp, but wasn't sure of the syntax of the code, again.

Comment: @DLR there were some typos, now it should be OK. And be sure to check the online regex checker tool

Comment: Thank you! Will definitely look into it, may also look into the SimpleDateFormat method as well. Because I am going to need to compare the different dates to each other as well.